# Selenium, how to modify headers on geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I am using python 3.6.5 and I was wondering how I could modify my headers on geckodriver, I tried the Firefox extension but it claimed geckodriver was not supported. How can I achieve my goals?